# How to use self-joining to calculate a historical rolling average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, average, self-join

I am trying to utilize self-joining in order to calculate 
rolling daily 1-yr averages across a list of tickers. The below code seems to provide an average across all tickers and dates, instead of providing unique results that would change for each ticker and date. (In other words, the third column in the output is the same all the way down, but each row should actually be unique).

Any advice here? thank you

```
SELECT [Ticker], [Date],
(SELECT AVG(T.[Close])
FROM [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] AS T
JOIN [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] AS O2
ON T.[Ticker] = O2.[Ticker]
AND T.[Date] between O2.[Date 250 Days Ago] AND O2.[Date])
FROM [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] AS O2
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect

Comment: And to answer your question, this is SQL Server 2012 and my own financial database. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `JOIN` in the subquery.  This is not necessary.  You just need a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT [Ticker], [Date],
       (SELECT AVG(T.[Close])
        FROM [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] AS T
        WHERE T.[Ticker] = O2.[Ticker] AND
              T.[Date] between O2.[Date 250 Days Ago] AND O2.[Date]
       ) as RollingAverage
FROM [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] AS O2;
```